# Keyboard keeps closing on TextField tap

Tags: flutter

I'm developing an app in Flutter. I'm debugging it on an Android Emulator.

I just created the Login Page, with the typical 2 fields username & password.

But when I tap on any of them, the keyboard keeps closing.

This video illustrates it: https://gyazo.com/11fd6b2bc80be29a8c1ec0250ce95f60

Does anyone know what's going on?

I'm getting this on the console as well:

```
W/IInputConnectionWrapper(15377): beginBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper(15377): getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper(15377): getTextAfterCursor on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper(15377): getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper(15377): endBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
```

Comment: do you delete your emulator cache?

Comment: It doesn't seem to be the emulator cache, because now I have tried on my physical phone and it's doing the same :/

Comment: unistall it from physical device and take a apk output from Build--> Build boundles apk and install apk to your phone.. if problem exist, that is because of your programming logic

Comment: I did what you mentioned, it keeps happening... What could it be?

Comment: You should post your code. From what it looks like, your widget is getting rebuilt onTap causing the widget to be rendered again. Do a print inside your build where you have your text box - if it is getting called when you tap the text field, you have to see what is building your widget again

Answer (score 0):

You may check your widget tree and see that it only usees 1 key value,
`GlobalKey<FormState> or UniqueKey()`